# Cross-package PluginLib Library Loading Error

Tags: ros, pluginlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Setup:

- Package A (`costmap_2d`) - Defined new plugin bass class `costmap_2d::CostmapPlugin`
- Package B (`static_costmap_plugin`) - Define plugin `costmap_plugins::StaticCostmapPlugin`
- In Manifest:
  `<export>`
    `<costmap_2d plugin="${prefix}/costmap_plugins.xml" />`
  `</export>`
- costmap_plugins.xml:

`<library path="lib/libcostmap_plugins">`

`<class name="static_costmap_plugin/static_costmap" type="costmap_plugins::StaticCostmap" base_class_type="costmap_2d::CostmapPlugin">`

`<description>Uses a static costmap</description>`

`</class>`
`</library>`

- Plugin Declaration:
  `PLUGINLIB_DECLARE_CLASS(costmap_plugins, static_costmap, costmap_plugins::StaticCostmapPlugin, costmap_2d::CostmapPlugin)`

Error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pluginlib::LibraryLoadException'
  what():  Failed to load library /home/dlu/ros/nav_experimental/static_costmap_plugin/lib/libcostmap_plugins.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Cannot load library: No manifest in /home/dlu/ros/nav_experimental/static_costmap_plugin/lib/libcostmap_plugins.so: static_costmap_plugin__static_costmap
Aborted
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37105/cross-package-pluginlib-library-loading-error/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2012-06-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [candronikos](https://answers.ros.org/users/5316/candronikos/) on 2013-07-04**:
To get this to work, what are the main differences between what you did and the tutorial? The main thing I would like to know is in which package did you declare you're plugin and if you had to turn your base class into a shared library for Package B to link with its plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out on my own.

Problem 1: The type attribute in the costmap_plugins.xml should refer to the namespaced version of the implementation class. Ergo `costmap_plugins::StaticCostmap` should be `static_costmap_plugin::StaticCostmapPlugin`.

Problem 2: The same applies to the first parameter of `PLUGINLIB_DECLARE_CLASS`

`PLUGINLIB_DECLARE_CLASS(static_costmap_plugin, static_costmap, static_costmap_plugin::StaticCostmapPlugin, costmap_2d::CostmapPlugin)`

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2012-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0